# Route all internet traffic through an Ubuntu VPS

Tags: proxy, vps

Similar question have been asked but I didn't find their answers sufficient, though I might be missing something.

I have a VPS running Ubuntu 12 and a laptop connected to a public wireless network. The network blocks traffic to and from some addresses which I want to access.

What's the easiest way to setup my traffic so it flows through my VPS?

I don't want just a HTTP proxy, I want to route other protocols as well.

Oh, I'm running Windows on my laptop.

Answer (score 2):

Set up an OpenVPN server on the VPS and use the OpenVPN client on your laptop.   Make sure the default route for the laptop is across the VPS.

You probably also need to set up NAT on the VPS server so it will correctly route your traffic.